# How to capture exact __LINE__ from inside struct?

Tags: c, struct

given the following code from somewhere inside a function:

```c
/* outside function we define myType */
typedef struct { ... } myType;

int fail_line;

/* code snippet from inside the function */
myType a = {
    .field1 = ...,
    .field2 = ...,
    .field3 = malloc(length * constant)  /* how to capture __LINE__ and store in fail_line here */
};

if (!a.field3) {
    printf("exception: malloc() at line %d failed to allocate %ld bytes of memory.\n",fail_line,length * constant);
    return FAIL;
}

return SUCCESS;
```

How can I capture the exact line number from the malloc statement?
(so I can write a verbose error message below, if `malloc()` returns `NULL`.)

Pls note that I don't want "workaround" answers, like "just close the type initialization with `}; fail_line = __LINE__ - 1;`".

If there is no way to do this, pls be explicit about it. Sometimes "it doesn't work" is also good to know for an answer.

Thanks in advance!

I'm currently using the workaround described to get around this.

Comment: You can use `.field3 = (fail_line = __LINE__, malloc(length * constant))`. You could also use `.field3 = foo(length * constant, &fail_line, __LINE__)` and put arbitrary code in `foo`, such as code that calls `malloc` and sets `fail_line` if and only if `malloc` returns a null pointer.

Comment: Curious: with such an explicit `if (!a.field3)`, where the warning is tied directly to the variable, does the *specific* line information really help that much here? Maybe I'm analyzing the example too literally, but in smaller programs the debug message might as well say *"Failed to allocate memory for a.field3 (in <function>)"*, which should be easily spotted. OTOH, as scope increases, maintaining parity between certain debug messages and the file line variables (or *variable*, a la `errno` (which introduces all the same issues `errno` has)) sounds potentially unwieldy.

Comment: Would a macro that expands to a call to a *wrapper* around `malloc` that prints debugging messages on failure not be preferable? (e.g., `#define dbg_malloc(x) (log_malloc((x), __LINE__, __FILE__, __func__))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below to save the line number in which the allocation occurred, use the `,` operator.

```
.field3 = (fail_line = __LINE__, malloc(length * constant);
```

As for me, I would rather know the file name and function name than the line number as they are more consistent over the life of code.

---

Also, the size received by `malloc()` is a `size_t` so:

```
// printf("exception: malloc() at line %d failed to allocate %ld bytes of memory.\n",
//     fail_line,length * constant);
printf("exception: malloc() at line %d failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory.\n",
    fail_line, (size_t)(length * constant));
```